# Compact operator, exercise 4.22 in Rudin's functional analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, compact-operators

Suppose that $X$ is a Banach space and $T$ is a compact operator in $\mathcal{B}(X)$. $\lambda\neq 0$ and let $S=\lambda I-T$.

> **Prove that:**
> (a) $\mathcal{N}(S^n)=\mathcal{N}(S^{n+1}) \Rightarrow \mathcal{N}(S^n)=\mathcal{N}(S^{n+k})$
> (b) There must be some integer $n$ s.t. $\mathcal{N}(S^n)=\mathcal{N}(S^{n+1})$
> (c) Let $n$ be the smallest integer that (a) holds, then $\dim\mathcal{N}(S^n)<\infty$, and $X=\mathcal{N}(S^n) \oplus \mathcal{R}(S^n)$, $S$ restricted on $\mathcal{R}(S^n)$ is a bijection.

I've proved (a)(b) and the 'bijection' part in (c) by showing that $\mathcal{N}(S^n) \cap \mathcal{R}(S^n)=\emptyset$, but I don't know how to prove the part $\dim\mathcal{N}(S^n)<\infty$ and $X=\mathcal{N}(S^n) + \mathcal{R}(S^n)$.

Also, I'm interested that if we have a smallest integer $n$ s.t. $\mathcal{N}(S^n)=\mathcal{N}(S^{n+1})$, then there will also be a smallest integer $m$ s.t. $\mathcal{R}(S^m)=\mathcal{R}(S^{m+1})$. So is it necessary that $m=n$? And if it's true, how can we prove that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $N(S^n) = N(S^{n+1})$ for some $n$, then $N(S^k) = N(S^{k+1})$ for all $k \ge n$, it follows from (a). Also if $R(S^m) = R(S^{m+1})$ then it holds for all $p \ge m$. So if we take $q \ge \max(n,m)$ we will get $N(S^q) = N(S^{q+1})$ and $R(S^q) = R(S^{q+1})$.

Comment: @Botnakov N. Sorry but I mean that m is the smallest integer that $\mathcal{R}(S^m)=\mathcal{R}(S^{m+1})$ holds. Let me edit it a bit.